# Can I use javascript or jquery with dynamic radio buttons generated from razor in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Hello All:  I am trying to toggle a div based on a "dynamic" radio button that was generated with razor:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                    {                       
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].DrugName)</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label class="form-label">Have you ever sold, smuggled, or transported for sale or personal Gain:</label><br />
                                <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Sold, "true", new { Id = "Sold_" + i, @class = "custom-control-input" })
                                    <span class="custom-control-label">Yes</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Sold, "false", new { Id = "Sold_" + i,  @class = "custom-control-input"})
                                    <span class="custom-control-label">No</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form=group col-md-2">
                                <label class="form-label">Have you ever used, possessed or experimented with?</label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Used, "true", new { Id = "Used_" + i,  @class = "custom-control-input" })
                                    <span class="custom-control-label">Yes</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Used, "false", new { Id = "Used_" + i,  @class = "custom-control-input"})
                                    <span class="custom-control-label">No</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
-----OTHER CODE-------REMOVED----------
```

using:

```
   var drugUseCount = document.getElementById("DrugUseCount").innerHTML;
  for (var i = 0; i < drugUseCount; i++) {
    $("input:radio[name='\\[0\\].Used']").click(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === true) {
        alert("True");
      } else if ($(this).val() === false) {
        alert("False");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I know I should be using "i" but I am literally just trying to capture the click or change event of the first item.  It just seems to ignore the event.  I have gotten myself all twisted up here and need some guidance.  Any help would be appreciated. I am at my wits end with this.

Comment: Since you have used Jquery, 'this.value' won't work because it won't recognize as a valid function. Try using this: $(this).val()===true and same for else if part.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will give that a try. I apologize, I have been in a frenzy of different attempts at many things to get this to work. Sloppy code at the moment!

Comment: No problem. Try this I hope this will help.

Comment: That did not solve it.  I have set breakpoint, it's like the element is not being found. I do not see any errors in debug window of chrome.  This line I believe is the problem: $("input:radio[name='\\[0\\].Used']").click(function() {

Comment: I see. Let's analyze it line by line. Where is the DrugUseCount coming from? I think it is not visible in the View you just provided.

Comment: I have div at bottom of partial view that uses index variable drugUseCount++

Comment: It renders the page with proper counts they shown as [0].Used for the name and I set the id= "Used_0".  There are 12 of them on the page so [1].Used, [2].Used etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Use the ternary operator in your razors html helper to add a class to the target element then bind click element on class name. This route could be more extensible if your requirements get more complicated in the future:

```
    <div class="form=group col-md-2">
        <label class="form-label">Have you ever used, possessed or experimented with?</label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Used, "true", i == 0 ? new { Id = "Used_" + i, @class = "custom-control-input drugUsed" } : new { Id = "Used_" + i, @class = "custom-control-input" })
            <span class="custom-control-label">Yes</span>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Used, "false", i == 0 ? new { Id = "Used_" + i, @class = "custom-control-input drugUsed" } : new { Id = "Used_" + i, @class = "custom-control-input" })
            <span class="custom-control-label">No</span>
        </label>
    </div>


    $(".drugUsed").click(function () {
        var eleId = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).val() == "true") {
            alert('true for element ' + eleId);
        } else {
            alert('false for element ' + eleId);
        }
    });
```

Option 2: use the jquery attribute selector since you know that razor will format the name of the element in a predictive manner.

```
$("input[name='[0].Used']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "true") {
            alert('true');
        } else {
            alert('false');
        }
});
```

This is assuming that your js file or script is located after the razor syntax or if you have it encapsulated in your document.ready function.

Comment: Yes sir! that'll do it.  You are a gentleman and a scholar. I am using option 1 for now by just adding the class name.  Option 2 I need to try again.  That one feels right but I don't think I was able to get it working within a loop dynamically where [0] would be in variable index [i].Used